# Find $f(x)$ if $f(x)=A\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\sin x\cos t\cdot f(t))dt+\sin x$, where $A$ is a constant

Tags: definite-integrals

> Find $f(x)$ if $f(x)=A\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\sin x\cos t\cdot f(t))dt+\sin x$, where $A$ is a constant.

$$f(x)=(A\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\cos t\cdot f(t))dt+1)\sin x\\=B\sin x,$$ where $B=A\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\cos t\cdot f(t))dt+1$  ....  $(1)$

Also, $f(t)=B\sin t$  ....  $(2)$

Putting $(2)$ in $(1)$,$$B=A\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\cos t\cdot B\sin t)dt+1\\\implies B=\frac{AB}2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin(2t)dt+1\\\implies B=AB+1 $$

Don't know if I am doing right and/or how to finish.

**EDIT:** @Nicolas asked to do double derivative. So, here is my attempt:

$$f(x)=B\sin x\\f'(x)=B\cos x\\f''(x)=-B\sin x\\\implies f^{"}(x)=-f(x)$$

I must add that solving second order differential equations is not in the syllabus.

Comment: Have you tried to differentiate $f$ twice?

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks. I have made an edit.

Comment: Just to explain my idea: the standard theory of ODEs states that, necessarily, $f(x)=\alpha\sin(x)+\beta\cos(x)$ for some constants $\alpha,\beta$ that you may be able to find by injecting this ansatz for $f$ into the integral.

Comment: Statement is confusing.  Find $f(x)$ and $f(t)=Bsin(t)$ seem at odds.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Maybe my attempt is wrong.

Comment: $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}sin(2t)dt=1$, not $2$, so$B=\frac{2}{2-A}$  What has this got to do with a differential equation?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I wonder the same. I was just shooting in the dark. I don't know what the correct apporach is.

Comment: Correct approach to what?  It looks like the only question is find B.